# According to Descartes, the mind and body communicate through a tiny part of the brain (the pineal gland) where the 'common sense' is located

Tags: descartes, mind-body, dualism

True or False?

I'm unsure about this question because it seems like he only refers to the mind and the brain in this context, but not the body as a whole.

Here's the passage:

"The mind isn't immediately affected by all parts of the
body but only by the brain-or perhaps just by the small part
of it which is said to contain the 'common sense'. [Descartes is
referring to the pineal gland. The 'common sense' was a supposed faculty,
postulated by Aristotle, whose role was to integrate the data from the five
specialized senses.] The signals that reach the mind depend
upon what state this part of the brain is in, irrespective
of the condition of the other parts of the body."

Comment: True. Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy has a long article dedicated to Descartes's peculiar belief, [Descartes and the Pineal Gland](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pineal-gland/).

Comment: I made an edit. You are welcome to roll this back or continue editing. You may see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. One thing to add is a source for the quote.  Welcome to this SE!

Comment: Can you provide the exact cite to Descartes‘s quote?